# Incorrect date format in Excel, while it's correct in CSV

Tags: php, csv

I am exporting a database table to csv and then when I open it in Excel I bump into a problem.
The column containing the date and time shows different format. It must have something to do with the AM and PM symbols, because as it can be seen on the enclosed image it cuts of the AM and the format also changes (2 instead of 02)

[image]

The ugly csv without the unnecessary columns:

```
"2013/02/13 20:23 PM"
"2013/02/13 20:26 PM"
"2013/02/13 23:27 PM"
"2013/02/13 23:27 PM"
"2013/02/14 01:01 AM"
"2013/02/16 22:50 PM"
"2013/02/17 19:26 PM"
"2013/02/21 01:19 AM"
"2013/02/26 04:27 AM"
"2013/02/27 01:03 AM"
"2013/02/28 04:53 AM"
"2013/02/28 04:53 AM"
"2013/02/28 04:53 AM"
"2013/03/01 03:54 AM"
"2013/03/06 04:23 AM"
"2013/03/06 04:23 AM"
"2013/03/10 10:27 AM"
"2013/03/10 10:35 AM"
"2013/03/10 10:39 AM"
"2013/03/10 10:48 AM"
"2013/03/10 23:25 PM"
"2013/03/11 04:12 AM"
"2013/03/11 04:50 AM"
"2013/03/11 04:51 AM"
"2013/03/11 04:52 AM"
```

Comment: I think its related to cell formatting... you can customize it

Comment: I need the import in the correct format, as the csv is downloaded by the users.

Comment: Can you show the part of the csv that corresponds to the data in the image above?

Comment: I replaced the image so you can see that the data is right.

Comment: Seeing the raw CSV data as well would still be helpful

Comment: I am not authorized to show it. I double checked and the selected part looks like this in the csv file: 2013/02/14 01:01 AM

Comment: MS Excel will load a CSV file according to its default settings: you can only control that for your own copy of Excel, not for anybody elses. If you need to control the formatting of dates, then you need to use a different file format such as Excel BIFF (.xls) or OfficeOpenXML (.xlsx) where you can specify exactly how dates should be formatted.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I added the raw csv

Comment: The date format doesn't make sense, maybe that's what's tripping up Excel. It's either `21:44` or `9:44 PM`. Can you try without the AM/PM suffix?

Comment: You are right, I missed it. I have to go now but I will get back to it later.

Comment: @Pekka웃 add your comment as solution as you were right. The wrong time format messed it up. The credit also goes for Mark Baker as I cannot set how the date and time should be formatted in Excel. Excel converts it to its default format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format doesn't make sense, maybe that's what's tripping up Excel.

It should be either 21:44 or 9:44 PM. Try without the AM/PM suffix, or convert the hours from 13-23 to 1-11.

Comment: The original format was 'H:i A' instead of 'h:i A'. That's what caused 20:23 PM